# How to echo a word based on previous echo word

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I have a form input and if script receive word tip (see if statement), it echo "do this" This work good

Now I want to echo another word based on previous word "do this" with if statement, but 
this not work

```
$at=(stripos($a, 'tip') === 0);
if ($at == true) {echo "do this";}
if (echoword == do this) {echo "do that";}
```

Comment: Why don't put both echo statements into the first if statement ?!

Comment: Simply try to explain what it is you want to do, not _how_ you imagine you _might_ be able to do it.

Comment: more experts are here but in my opinion if `$do="do this";` variable pre defined , then `if ($at == true) {echo $do;}` and again `if ($do == "do this") {echo "do that";}`

Comment: I want to set two result first is do this and second is based on first result, I do not know the right string for this so I used echoword, I want if first echo is do this then second echo should be do that

Comment: i believe i understand what do you want to do, look at my answer below, is  that how you wanted it ? or do you want to do it in a different way ?

Answer (score 0):

you cant not rely on "previous echo" just rely on condition like this:

```
$at=(stripos($a, 'tip') === 0);
if ($at == true) {
echo "do this";
echo "do that";
}
```

becaus in this case your "previous echo" depends only on that condition

IF - is a basic control structure.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do it like this

```
$at=(stripos($a, 'tip') === 0);
if ($at == true) {
    $echoword="do this";
    echo $echoword;
}
if (isset($echoword) && $echoword == 'do this'){
     echo "do that";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which one you prefer?
1. Put your code in existence `if` statement.

```
$at=(stripos($a, 'tip') === 0);
if ($at == true) {echo "do this"; echo "do that";}
```

2. Use `$at` whenever you want to write related thing.

```
$at=(stripos($a, 'tip') === 0);
if ($at == true) {echo "do this";}
if ($at) {echo "do that";}
```

3. Store the echoed word in variable

```
$at=(stripos($a, 'tip') === 0);
$echoed = '';
if ($at == true) {echo "do this"; $echoed = "do this";}
if ($echode == "do this") {echo "do that";}
```

Comment: Thank you, store the variable works fine and I get both results

Comment: @prabhu you're welcome. And also you can mark and point the answers ;)